# Import errors in telegram bot (python-telegram-bot)

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot written using python-telegram-bot that was working fine but after a few weeks, when I start the script, it seems like it cannot find some libraries & modules.

As an example, "Update" is widely used in my code and it was working just fine. But now it cannot be found by python.

Here are some of my imports.

```
    from telegram import  Update, ForceReply, InlineQueryResultArticle, InputTextMessageContent, ReplyKeyboardRemove, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update, User, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, Contact, Message, KeyboardButton
```

And here is the error.

```
    async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
NameError: name 'Update' is not defined
```

Does anyone know any solution?

I tried moving to a new environment, reinstalling python-telegram-bot with --pre or --upgrade switches, clearing the python cache and reloading the vs code ssh window.

Comment: Have you used an environment while developing?  Are you using the same environment to run the bot?

Comment: I connect to a VPS remotely (using vs code remote-ssh extension), edit the code via vs code, create a docker file, then run the bot in a docker container.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this `pip install telegram`
Only install the *python-telegram-bot* library,

for now let's create a new environment and try again:

```
$ deactivate  # check if you've active environment
$ python -m venv newenv

$.\newenv\Scripts\activate   # for windows
$ source newenv/bin/activate # for mac or linux
```

then install the library:

```
$ pip install python-telegram-bot -U
```

Now try to run your bot:

```
$ python main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good way to transfer environments to production (Correct me if I am wrong), however, you can build a new environment using the exact same packages that are installed in your environment using:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This saves every package you used in the development env in a file.
Then you can use this file in a docker file to build the exact same dependencies your bot was developed with, using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the recommendation reistall dependency and it works for me. (Although PyCharm IDE still says "could not find reference", bot starts working fine):

```
pip uninstall python-telegram-bot
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

Comment: I guess the problem is with the version of python-telegram-bot. When I re-installed it with the latest version, it seemed to be resolved. Thank you!